# Direct AR launch using A-Frame

Tags: augmented-reality, aframe

AR button is not available on iPhone

on Android, the user needs to click on AR button to launch AR. Can we directly launch AR on the loading URL?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The scene object has an [enterAR](https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/blob/v1.2.0/src/core/scene/a-scene.js#L261) function, which you can invoke when the scene is loaded (or at any other time):

```
<script>
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener("loaded", evt => {
      try {
        this.el.sceneEl.enterAR();
      } catch (error) {
        alert(error)
      }
    })
  }
})
</script>
<a-scene foo>
</a-scene>
```

Something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/qbvednom/)